# Codes inside callback not running

Tags: java, android, interface

I am newbie in java . I stucked to this problem. All looks fine to me .
Codes :

**testCall.java**

```
package com.example.callbacktest;

public interface testcall {
    public void onEvent();
}
```

**testLibrary.java**

```
  package com.example.callbacktest;

  public class testLibrary {

      testcall listener;
       public testLibrary(){

        }
        public void createSession(  testcall callback ){
            this.listener = callback;
            System.out.println("Out from library");
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.callbacktest;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        testLibrary obj = new testLibrary();
        obj.createSession(new testcall(){

            @Override
            public void onEvent() {
                System.out.println("OUT from onEvent");

            }

        });
    }

}
```

System logs only printing "Out from library" . It Should also print "OUT from onEvent" .
Codes inside callback not running. I dont understand what i am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to `listener.onEvent()` in your test library.

Comment: Where should i add this ? In constructor ?

Comment: It's your decision. Just make sure you've assigned a value to `listener` before that.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling callback method in your `testLibrary` class

change your method like this in your testLibrary class

```
 public void createSession(  testcall callback ){
        this.listener = callback;
        System.out.println("Out from library");
        listener.onEvent();  //Added line
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,  I have to tick laalto answer , he replied first , Thanks anyway :)